# Threading makes my program not responding?

Tags: vb.net

Hey here is my script:

```
Private Sub UpdateThread()
        Dim AppDir As String = Application.StartupPath()
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(MyUpdate.UpdateFetchURL, UpdateClass.WebUpdateZIP, True, True)
        MyUpdate.ExtractArchive(UpdateClass.WebUpdateZIP, AppDir)
        File.Delete(UpdateClass.WebUpdateZIP)
    End Sub
```

How i call it:

```
Private Sub FetchUpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FetchUpdateButton.Click
        FetchUpdateButton.Enabled = False
        Dim trd As New Thread(AddressOf UpdateThread)
        trd.IsBackground = True
        trd.Start()
        Do
            ProgressBar1.Increment(5)
            ProgressBar1.Increment(2)
        Loop
    End Sub
```

It does perfectly the UpdateThread task, but program just hangs. That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting a loop with no condition to ever exit that loop.